# Ordered lists in HTML to PDF conversion using iTextSharp (C#, MVC)

Tags: c#, html, pdf, model-view-controller, itext

I'm trying to convert some HTML code into PDF file using iTextSharp. And It's working with one problem. I have some ordered lists and they are displaying but without bullets/numbers (I tested both OL and UL) and I can't figure out how to do this without manually parsing HTML code and inserting numbers at the beginning of each li element.

```
_topic.Body = "<ol><li>First</li><li>Second</li></ol>";

using (FileStream msOutput = new FileStream("file.pdf", FileMode.Create))
{
    TextReader reader = new StringReader(_topic.Body);
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, msOutput);
    HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);

    document.Open();
    worker.StartDocument();
    worker.Parse(reader);
    worker.EndDocument();
    worker.Close();
    document.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with iText 7 and pdfHTML?

Comment: I tried and it works good enough but the problem is the license, I already have iTextSharp (5) so I can use this or other that is free (commercial use). I tried PdfSharp and the problem with this is splitting lines between pages (half of the line is on previous page, and other half on next page). Maybe this will be easier to fix?

Comment: I do not understand your concern about licensing because iText(Sharp) 5 and iText 7 .NET have exactly the same license, but that is not a technical question, it is a legal question. Only technical questions are allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you do not want to upgrade, at least replace `HTMLWorker` with `XMLWorker`.

Comment: XMLWorker works correctly. Surprisingly free version of iTextSharp (LGPL) worked correctly as well. Thanks!

Comment: You write that you use iText(Sharp) 5. That version is *not* LGPL but AGPL. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, we have iTextSharp 5 for commercial use (bought or something), but there is also available iTextSharp-LGPL which is older version I think. So I installed this one because It works properly in this case and I'm sure I can use It. As mentioned before, it's not place for this topic. So using iTextSharp-LGPL solved my problem in every aspect.

Comment: If you have a commercial license of iText then most likely you also have a support contract and then you don't need to use Stack Overflow, you can contact iText Software directly and ask for a supported solution.